# Convolution with an Hölder-function is an Hölder-function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, holder-spaces

Let $s\in(0,1)$, $n>2s$, $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ open and bounded, let $u\in C^{0,2s+\epsilon}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $\epsilon>0$ is small, such that: $u=0$, on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega$, let:
$$ v(x):=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|y|^{2s-n}u(x-y)\,dy,\qquad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n,$$
is true that: $v\in C^{0,2s+\epsilon}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. The only thing that i have obtain is that, for any $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$, by hypothesis:
$$ |u(x_1)-u(x_2)|\leq C|x-y|^{2s+\epsilon},$$
than:
$$|v(x_1)-v(x_2)|\leq|x_1-x_2|^{2s+\epsilon}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|y|^{2s-n}\,dy, $$
but the problem is that:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|y|^{2s-n}=\infty.$$
I have no idea how to proceed, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's because you are disregarding that $u$ has compact support. Try to use that assumption.

Comment: i don't know how to use this hypothesis. Can you give me the details please?

Comment: No, $ |u(x_1)-u(x_2)|\le C|x-y|^{2s+\epsilon}$ is impossible unless $2s+\epsilon\le1$ (or $u$ is constant). You're going to need to look up the actual definition of $C^{0,\alpha}$.

Comment: There is a mistacke, $s\in(0,1/2)$ and $\epsilon$ is such that $2s+\epsilon\in (0,1)$